# Maximum of discretized Gaussian process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Consider a stationary discrete Gaussian process $(X^{\lambda}_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with mean function $m(x) = 0$ and covariance function $$k(n,m) = e^{-\lambda|m-n|}.$$
You can think of it as a discretization of the stationary Ornstein--Uhlenbeck process with drift coefficient $\lambda$. Fix $N \in \mathbb N$ and consider the random variables
$$Y^{\lambda} = \max_{0\leq n \leq N} |X^\lambda_n|, \qquad
Y^{\infty} = \max_{0\leq n \leq N} |Z_n|, \qquad Z_n \sim \mathcal N(0, 1) \quad \text{i.i.d.}.
$$
You can think of $Y^\infty$ as a weak limit of $Y^{\lambda}$ as $\lambda \to \infty$. Intuitively, it seems clear that $\lambda \mapsto \mathbb E[Y^{\lambda}]$ should be an increasing function of $\lambda$, and in particular that $\mathbb E[Y^{\lambda}] \leq \mathbb E[Y^{\infty}]$. Does either of these two facts follow from standard theory?

Comment: I can prove the inequality without $| \cdot |$. Are sure that it holds by doing some numerical checks?

Comment: I think that part of the statement definitely holds. I just answered my own question below with a tentative proof.

Comment: I your proof for the second question, could you highlight where you have used the specific assumptions considered above. How can this be generalized for other cases?

Comment: The structure of the covariance is used to prove that $g(\, \cdot \, ; \alpha)$ is indeed a non-decreasing function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\range}[2]{\{#1, \dotsc, #2\}}
\newcommand{\proba}{\mathbb P}
\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb R}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm d}
\newcommand{\expect}{\mathbb E}$$
I prove below that $\expect [Y^{\lambda}] \leq \expect [Y^{\infty}]$.

**Step 1.**
For $n \in \range{0}{N}$,
let
$
    M^{\lambda}_n := \max\bigl\{ |X^\lambda_0|, \dotsc, |X^\lambda_{n}| \bigr\}.
$
We first prove that the following inequality holds
for all $R \geq 0$ and $n \in \range{0}{N}$:
\begin{equation}
    \tag{1}
    \proba \Bigl[ \lvert X^\lambda_n \rvert \leq R \, \Big| \, M^\lambda_{n} \leq R \Bigr]
    \geq
    \proba \Bigl[ \lvert X^\lambda_n \rvert \leq R \Bigr].
\end{equation}
To this end, fix $R \geq 0$ and introduce the probability measures $\nu \colon \mathcal B(\real) \to [0, 1]$
and $\nu_n \colon \mathcal B(\real) \to [0, 1]$ given by
\begin{align}
    \nu(A) &= \proba \bigl[ |X^\lambda_0| \in A \bigr] \\
    \nu_n(A) &= \proba \bigl[ |X^\lambda_n| \in A \,\bigm|\, M^\lambda_n \leq R \bigr].
\end{align}
Denote by $F \colon \real \to [0, 1]$ and $F^n\colon \real \to [0, 1]$ the associated cumulative distribution functions.
The inequality (1) will follow
once we have proved that $F_n(\alpha) \geq F(\alpha)$ uniformly in $\alpha \in \real$.
This is clearly true for $n = 0$.
Reasoning by induction, we assume that $F_{n-1} \geq F$ and prove that $F_n \geq F$.
To this end let $g \colon \real_{\geq 0} \times \real \to [0, 1]$ be given by
$$
    g(x; \alpha) = \proba \Bigl[ |X^\lambda_n| \leq \alpha \,\Big\vert\, |X^\lambda_{n-1}| = x \Bigr].
$$
Note that $g(\,\cdot\,; \alpha)$ is a non-decreasing function and that, by stationarity,
\begin{equation}
    \tag{2}
    \int_{\real} g(x; \alpha) \, \d \nu(\alpha) = F(\alpha).
\end{equation}
For all $\alpha \in \real_{\geq 0}$,
we have that
\begin{align*}
    F_n(\alpha)
&\geq \proba \Bigl[ |X^\lambda_n| \leq \alpha \, \Big| \, M^X_{n-1} \leq R \Bigr]  \\
&= \frac{
    \expect \left[ \mathbf 1_{\left\{|X_n| \leq \alpha\right\}}
    \mathbf 1_{\left\{M^X_{n-1} \leq R\right\}} \right]
}{\proba \left[ M^X_{n-1} \leq R \right]}
= \frac{
    \expect \left[ \expect \Bigl[ \mathbf 1_{\left\{\left\lvert X_n \right\rvert \leq \alpha\right\}} \, \middle\vert \,  M_{n-1}, \lvert X_{n-1} \rvert \Bigr]
    \mathbf 1_{\left\{M^X_{n-1} \leq R\right\}} \right]
}{\proba \left[ M^X_{n-1} \leq R \right]} \\
&= \frac{
    \expect \left[ g\bigl(\lvert X_{n-1} \rvert; \alpha\bigr)
    \mathbf 1_{\left\{M_{n-1} \leq R\right\}} \right]
}{\proba \left[ M_{n-1} \leq R \right]}
= \expect \bigl[ g\bigl(\lvert X_{n-1} \rvert; \alpha\bigr) \,\big\vert \, M_{n-1} \leq R \bigr].
\end{align*}
Using the definition of $\nu_{n}$ and $\nu$,
we obtain
$$
    F_n(\alpha)
    \geq \int_{\real} g(x; \alpha) \, \nu_{n-1}(\d x)
    \geq \int_{\real} g(x; \alpha) \, \nu(\d x) = F(\alpha).
$$
The last equality is (2)
and in the second inequality,
we used the induction hypothesis together with the fact that,
for any real-valued random variables $U$ and $V$ with cumulative distribution functions satisfying $F_U \geq F_V$ everywhere,
it holds for any non-negative non-decreasing function $g\colon \real \to \real$ that
$
\expect \left[ g(U) \right] \leq \expect \left[ g(V) \right].
$
Indeed in this case $F_{g(U)} \geq F_{g(V)}$,
so
$$
    \expect \left[ g(U) \right]
    = \int_{0}^{\infty} 1 - F_{g(U)}(x) \, \d x
    \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} 1 - F_{g(V)}(x) \, \d x
    = \expect \left[ g(V) \right].
$$

**Step 2**.
We prove that
\begin{align}
    \tag{3}
    \proba \left[ Y^{\lambda} \geq R \right]
    \leq
    \proba \left[ Y^{\infty} \geq R \right].
\end{align}
To this end let
$
    L_n = \max\bigl\{ |X^\lambda_0|, \dotsc, |X^\lambda_{n}|, |Z_{n+1}|, \dotsc, \lvert Z_{N} \rvert \bigr\}.
$
Since $L_0 = Y^{\infty}$ in law and $L_{N} = Y^{\lambda}$,
the claim (3) will follow from the inequality
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:incremental_inequality}
    \forall n \in \range{0}{N-1},
    \qquad
    \proba \left[ L_{n+1} \geq R \right]
    \leq
    \proba \left[ L_n \geq R \right].
\end{equation}
Fix $n \in \range{0}{N-1}$.
It holds that
\begin{align*}
    \proba \left[ L_{n+1} \geq R \right]
    &= 1 - \proba \left[ M^X_n \leq R \right] \proba \left[ X^\lambda_{n+1} \leq R \, \middle| M^X_n \leq R \right] \Bigl(\proba \left[Z_{n+2} \leq R \right] \times \dotsc \times \proba \left[Z_{J-1} \leq R \right]\Bigr), \\
    \proba \left[ L_n \geq R \right]
    &= 1 - \proba \left[ M^X_n \leq R \right] \Bigl(\proba \left[Z_{n+1} \leq R \right] \times \dotsc \times \proba \left[Z_{J-1} \leq R \right]\Bigr).
\end{align*}
Therefore, inequality (3) follows from **Step 1**.
The conclusion then follows from
$$
\expect \Bigl[ \left\lvert Y^{\lambda} \right\rvert^p \Bigr]
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \proba \Bigl[ \left\lvert Y^{\lambda} \right\rvert^p \geq R \Bigr] \, \d R
\leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \proba \Bigl[ \left\lvert Y^{\infty} \right\rvert^p \geq R \Bigr] \, \d R
= \expect \Bigl[ \left\lvert Y^{\infty} \right\rvert^p \Bigr].
$$